Trying to cluster short survey answers (1 to 10 words). Am I on the right track?
Here's the explanation of what i want to fully make (its a project for school).

A user just puts in a file with just the answers to whatever question was asked in the survey.

2.The machine finds similar answers and groups them under one label or cluster that is unnamed (thinking of using MeanShift, GMM, KMeans)

If possible I would also like it to generate a label for the cluster.

4.Write the clustered and labeled answers back into a file to be checked and used for whatever purpose.
Some context on the data: lots of short (with some long, 10+ words) answers like "i dont know", "??", "helpful", "red", etc. and each has anywhere from 200 to 2000 answers.The answers are in dutch or french, would it be recomanded I translate them to english for better performance? Usually there are around 7 to 20 (high amounts are rare) clusters. I also have the right labels for the answers so I can check if the algorithm has clustered correctly.
I have tried looking into it and I need to vectorize my texts first, for this I tried TF-IDF and Count vectorizer in scikit. I also found their cheat sheet and It recommands i use MeanShift.
I havent tried looking for the best parameters yet, but the performance seem very poor (close to random). I used Adjusted Rand Index, Normalized Mutual Information and Silhouette Score to evbaluate.
Am I on the right track or are there better things out there? Vectorization methods, embeddings, clustering algorithms?
Edit: I just realized something that may overthrow the algorithm. In each survey there is a category named ´others´. It is a category with actual answers that are just irrelevant.
Possible workaroud i think way work: The gategory is ´small´ with around 8%. My clustering algorithm always makes way too many classes, but i could try to figure out a balance between combining classes of 1 or 2 answers into ´others´.

Your approach is good if everything was in the same language and you weren't worried about synonyms (red vs. maroon). With multiple languages, it will be tough to get good comparisons when only looking at word overlap as languages have different words for the same concepts. Deep sentence transformers can solve both the synonym and language problems. You can use these models to generate embeddings (vectors) which will point in a similar direction for similar multilingual texts. Here's one I found: https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/distiluse-base-multilingual-cased-v2.

Thank you so much! I will for sure look into it. I've just made an edit to my post containing a problem that I think is essential to fix for my clustering to work. I don't know if you have any experience with that.

Regarding combining clusters I would recommend using a hierarchical clustering algorithm like HDBSCAN. This way, you can specify if you want categories to be larger or smaller without needing to specify a concrete quantity. You can read more here: https://dashee87.github.io/data%20science/general/Clustering-with-Scikit-with-GIFs/#:~:text=in%20this%20case.-,Hierarchical%20Clustering,-Unlike%20k%2Dmeans
